# Laravel - change mime-type of a file on the request object

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types

I'm uploading a file with `dwf` extension.

However doing `$request->file('dwf_file')->extension()` giving me `bin` instead of `dwf` and the mime-type on the file is wrongly set to `application/octet-stream` might be the reason why it is guessing it to be a binary file.

Now I'm trying to change the mime-type on the fly, before validation kicks-in:

```
$file = $request->file('dwf_file');

$request->merge([
    'dwf_file' =>
      new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile(
         $file->getPath(),
         $file->getClientOriginalName(),
         'model/vnd.dwf' // correct mime-type
     )
]);

$request->validate(...); // fails because uploaded file's extension is not dwf
```

It doesn't work, I think mainly because merge only deals with input source and not files.

So, How do I change the `dwf_file` to a new instance of `UploadedFile`? Or can I change mime-type on the exisiting `UploadedFile` instance? I couldn't find any `setMimeType` method on this class.

What are my options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getClientOriginalExtension`.It will return  `dwf extension` .

```
$request->file('dwf_file')->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

And `$request->file('dwf_file')->extension()` will return `bin`.

You can get mimeType using

```
$request->file('dwf_file')->getMimeType() or getClientMimeType()
```

this will return `"application/octet-stream"`

In form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

As a side note

**getClientOriginalExtension()**

Returns the original file extension.It is extracted from the original file name that was uploaded.Then it should not be considered as a safe value.

**Updated**

I think `dwf` extension not working properly for mimes validation.Because dwf files upload return `bin` as mimes.So better create custom validation

```
  'dwf_file' => ['file','mimeTypes:application/octet-stream', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

            if ($value->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'dwf') {
                    $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
                }
            }],
```

Comment: My validation is failing `['dwf' => 'file|mimes:dwf']`. Even though I'm uploading a `dwf` extensioned file, it's saying that the file is invalid. How do I get around it?

Comment: `['dwf' => 'file|mimes:dwf']`

Comment: ['dwf_file' => 'file|mimes:dwf']  .it should be.can you show full vaidation code

Comment: ah yes apologies. that was a typo. it is: `['dwf_file' => 'file|mimes:dwf']`

Comment: yes dwf failed .but     'logo' => ['file','mimes:dwf','mimeTypes:application/octet-stream'],  mimetypes works fine.will check and let you know if anythink can be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233714/discussion-between-sumit-wadhwa-and-john-lobo).

Comment: you can write custom validation based on mimeTypes and client original extension.if you add mimes bin then it works fine but not good i guess